# Can bootstrap grid contain more than 12 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I offten see such code in markup : `<div class='col-md-23'>`, but as I know bootstrap grid has 12 columns. So, what meens `col-md-23`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bootstrap customize page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) allows you to dynamically set the amount of columns in the grid.

Comment: sorry, it`s really a customized bootstrap. Thanks, for answer!